# Windows Batch matching a string

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

In the end I want to match a string and use that value.

I have a lot of folders called TEST123456 with different numbers in different places on my computer.
Using `dir TEST?????? /s /b /a:d > folders.txt` I can get a file which looks something like:

```
C:/folder1/folder2/TEST123456
C:/folder1/folder2/TEST654321
C:/folder2/TEST246810
```

Now this list will be very large so I want it sorted by the number. I want to change this file to:

```
TEST123456C:/folder1/folder2/TEST123456
TEST654321C:/folder1/folder2/TEST654321
TEST246810C:/folder2/TEST246810
```

and it would be preferable but not neccesary to already do this when inserting the lines in the text file.

Now I tried using `findstr TEST...... folders.txt` but it prints the whole line and I only want the matching string. I'm very beginner at Windows Batch so I think it should be relatively easy to create what I want.

Comment: what do you mean `sorted by the number`?

Comment: So the hard thing is I want to extract the TEST123456 to the front (and also keep it at the end). When this is done I can easily sort it using the command sort and then search the list very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FOR /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to loop through folders:

```
@echo off
>folders.txt (
for /D /R %%A in (test??????) do echo %%~nxA%%A
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works! I'm very bad at this language so maybe you could also help me make it exactly like this, only that `%%~nxA` (which is the folder name as far as I know) limit to 6 characters. Sometimes the name of the folder is `TEST123456, this folder is for testing` and then I only want to extract the first 6 characters. I did not include this in my initial question because I thought I could do it myself but it turns out I have a lot to learn!